# Getting the number of users for this year and last year in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table structure like this

| root_tstamp | userId |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-26T00:13:24.725+00:00 | d2212 |
| 2022-01-26T00:13:24.669+00:00 | ad323 |
| 2022-01-26T00:13:24.629+00:00 | adfae |
| 2022-01-26T00:13:24.573+00:00 | adfa3 |
| 2022-01-26T00:13:24.552+00:00 | adfef |
| ... | ... |
| 2021-01-26T00:12:24.725+00:00 | d2212 |
| 2021-01-26T00:15:24.669+00:00 | daddfe |
| 2021-01-26T00:14:24.629+00:00 | adfda |
| 2021-01-26T00:12:24.573+00:00 | 466eff |
| 2021-01-26T00:12:24.552+00:00 | adfafe |

I want to get the number of users in the current year and in previous year like below using SQL.

| Date | Users | previous_year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 10 | 5 |
| 2022-01-02 | 20 | 15 |

and the query I have used is:

```
with base as (
  select 
    date(root_tstamp) as current_date
    , count(distinct userid) as signup_counts
  from table1
  group by 1
)
select 
  t1.current_date
  , t1.signup_counts as signups_this_year
  , t2.signup_counts as signups_last_year
  , t1.signup_counts - t2.signups_counts as difference
  from base t1 
  left join base t2 on t1.current_date = t2.current_date + interval '1 year'
    group by t1.current_date
    order by t1.current_date Desc
```

But I getting this error:
ERROR: column t2.signups_counts does not exist

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have `t2.signup_counts` is misspelled as `t2.signups_counts`.

Another note is that your query only has a `GROUP BY` on `current_date` and since the other columns are not aggregates you've to include these columns too.

Here is the modified query:

```
    with base as (
  select 
    date(root_tstamp) as current_date
    , count(distinct userid) as signup_counts
  from table1
  group by 1
)
select 
  t1.current_date
  , t1.signup_counts as signups_this_year
  , t2.signup_counts as signups_last_year
  , t1.signup_counts - t2.signup_counts as difference
  from base t1 
  left join base t2 on t1.current_date = t2.current_date - interval '1 year'
    group by t1.current_date, t2.signup_counts, t1.signup_counts
    order by t1.current_date Desc
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, that issue has been solved. But now I getting this error
ERROR: column "root_tstamp" does not exist in t1, t2, unnamed_join

Comment: I created a running sample: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g5KJKdAwbjgZkze2gWSTVX/0. Also note that I replaced `+ interval '1 year'` to `- interval '1 year'` since you're trying to find sign ups from last year. Is this consistent with what you're trying to do?